# CakePHP cake bake giving error after selecting default

Tags: cakephp, php

I just created a new project with CakePHP according to the main page you get after configuring everything i'm all in the green even database connection.

i run this command:

```
octavius@octavius-VirtualBox:/opt/lampp/htdocs/acltutorial/cake/console$ ./cake bake all
```

and this happens:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v1.3.7 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /opt/lampp/htdocs/acltutorial/app
---------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------
Bake All
---------------------------------------------------------------
Use Database Config: (default/test) 
[default] > 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_query() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/acltutorial/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 600

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/acltutorial/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 600
```

I went into my php.ini file and added extension = 'mysql.so' and it still doesn't work. Anybody have any ideas?

PS: Doing table by table yields the same error

EDIT: After doing what dogmatic69 suggested i got these warnings:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/acltutorial/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 552

Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/acltutorial/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 552
PHP Warning:  mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/acltutorial/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 558

    Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/acltutorial/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 558
    PHP Warning:  mysql_get_server_info() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/acltutorial/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 566

    Warning: mysql_get_server_info() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/acltutorial/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 566
    PHP Warning:  mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/acltutorial/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 600

    Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/acltutorial/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php on line 600
    Your database does not have any tables.
```

Still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you set a symbolic link to SQL in your apache file?

Comment: I believe not can you explain how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't a cake error, apparently I had to specify the port in the database.php file like so:

```
'port' => '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

it couldn't connect to the database for baking, though it worked for the app itself, this fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

undo the changes you have made and then do something like this

sudo apt-get install php5-mysql

sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: What if my mysql and apache are the ones bundled with xampp?

Comment: if you were using that it should work out the box. no clue why its broken then

Comment: I edited my question to reflect the new errors after what you suggested. I have no idea what's going on and checking in google everyone that has this problem is using windows.

Comment: Also it's worth mentioning that i'm just doing the CakePHP tutorials. I did the first one "manually" without Cake Bake and I had no problems

Comment: then its because mysql is not setup on cli, it is separate from web based php.

Comment: How would i go about setting it up?

Answer (score 0):

It's not CakePHP error for sure. This means that mysql library is not loaded. When you added the extension did you restart the server? run phpinfo() in a file and see if the mysql is loaded.

Comment: i hadn't it yielded the following error Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mysql.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

So i removed it

Answer (score 0):

This was running me crazy as well. I am on Ubuntu with XAMPP. Managed to fix it using 8vius' solution
In the /app/config/database.php file

> 'port' => '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock'